# How to automatically create a new gemset with rvm when creating a new Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I find that I typically create a new gemset for each new project, so would like to automate creating a gemset to install that app's gems into, rather than having to do it manually. I've tried searching around for ways to do it, and haven't found what I'm looking for.

Comment: you can just add a `.ruby-gemset` file into the root of your project, then, when going into the directory, if the gemset doesn't exists, rvm will create it automatically

Comment: And you might want to create a rails app template which creates this .ruby-gender file whenever you run `rails new` https://guides.rubyonrails.org/rails_application_templates.html This is a great idea. If I crack it properly I’ll follow up; I want to do this too.